# How to correctly portray sign language between multiple characters

Tags: fiction, dialogue, language

I am writing a book where one of the main characters only uses sign language to communicate, and all of the speaking characters communicate using ASL whilst also speaking aloud at the same time.

Is there a way to portray this without simply implying that every conversation is also being signed?

Comment: There are quite a few [questions and answers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=sign+language) about how to represent sign language in written books. Maybe one of them answers your own question? For example, look at this question: [How does one include sign language in a dialogue?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/how-does-one-include-sign-language-in-a-dialogue)

Comment: @Dyllan - I suspect this question will be "voted closed" as a duplicate. Don't fret! That doesn't mean it's a bad question, just that there's already a question/answer on the site that covers it. Welcome!

Comment: Can you say how there being multiple characters the way you portray sign language?

Answer (score 1):

Some broad do's and do not's include:

1. Don't go into great detail about the sign itself. For example saying "He gestured his thanks," is good but not "He raised a hand to his mouth, 3 fingers touching before pulling it down." This should be done sparingly and only if wanting to emphasise or subtly teach the reader a specific sign.
2. As it is a noted language, italics or some special font aren't needed, quotation marks are fine.
3. Remember that although voice isn't an option, gesture is. Instead of saying "The anger was evident in her voice, you could say, "Her hands gesticulated aggressively, jabbing sharply in my direction." Emotion and tone remains and voice isn't needed to show that. Animatedly could mean happy, sharply could mean angry, slowly could mean confused, quickly could mean scared, etc.
4. Linking to the point above, deaf people are the same as people who speak using voice in the *manner* of by which they communicate. For one thing, I know deaf people who mumble, making small gestures before turning back and speaking more clearly.

Once you've made it clear the character signs, you don't need to include reminders every single time. The reader will learn to fill it in in their heads. Adding small reminders like "She signed," "He gestured," "They motioned," are good alternatives instead of speaking but longer reminders like "He stared at her quickly moving hands, brain so sluggish he found it hard to understand what she was saying."

But to answer specifically to your question, once you've emphasised enough that that character signs to communicate, the reader will understand this whenever they speak and will only need occasional reminders to ground their reality again.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean to imply that deaf people are not human! (Point 4)

Comment: Oh man yeah I really didn't. I think I meant to say "The same as humans who speak using voice." Thanks for pointing that out - I'll go and change it now!